# SVG importation issue in Vite upon upgrade to version 5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, vite

Upon the upgrade of

```
 vite                             4.5.0  →  5.0.2
 vite-plugin-svgr                 3.3.0  →  4.2.0
```

in our react project, we suddenly get the following errors

```
Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent'. Did you mean to use 'import ReactComponent from "*.svg"' instead?

import { ReactComponent as NewIcon } from '@shared/assets/icons/new.svg';
```

However, with the old versions, everything has been working. How can I resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your import statement like this :

`import NewIcon from '@shared/assets/icons/new.svg';`

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. However, then I get new errors like

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<CustomIconComponentProps | SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>> | ForwardRefExoticComponent<CustomIconComponentProps> | undefined'.

<Icon component={NewIcon} className="text-[10px] leading-none text-white" />`